# How to split main.js into smaller chunks in Angular 15 and Standalone Component?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 15 website that already use standalone component and lazy loading everything in my project. At this moment, the main.js in production build is 578.02KB. I’d like the make it smaller. Here is my profiling result:

[image]

Is it possible to make it smaller? I mean I want to split some of the package to another js file. I don’t know how to do it. Anyone could share experience?

Comment: maybe set "vendorChunk" to true so you get slimmer main & 3rd party content into vendor.